# Could quantum wave be beating between two components?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If i look de Broglie equation

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{m\gamma v}$$ , where $\gamma$ is Lorentz gamma factor $$ \gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2} $$

and change that to the equation
for frequency $f = v/\lambda$, i get following equation:

$$ f = m\gamma v^2/h $$ .

What is interesting here is that there is identity $$ \gamma v^2 = c^2(\gamma-1/\gamma)$$
and i can write this equation in the form

$$ f = \frac{mc^2(\gamma-1/\gamma)}{h} $$

I just have a thought that could i by any means interpret this equation to be equation
for beating? such that

$$ f_{beating} = f_2 - f_1 $$

where
$$f_2 = \frac{mc^2}{h}\gamma $$

and

$$f_1 = \frac{mc^2}{h}\frac{1}{\gamma} $$ ?

$f_1$ and $f_2$ depends on the velocity and if v->0 the $f_1$ and $f_2$ becomes close to

$$ f_1 \rightarrow mc^2/h $$

$$ f_2 \rightarrow mc^2/h $$

$$ f_{beating} \rightarrow 0 $$

That would mean there is some kind of frequency related to the mass of the particle $f = mc^2/h$ that spreads to two components when particle starts to move.

Is this meaningful?

$ f/m = c^2/h $ is very high quantity,

$$c^2/h = \frac{(2.998*10^8 [m/s])^2}{6.62607*10^{-34}[m^2kg/s]} = 1.3565 * 10^{50} hz/kg$$

This is or may be sligthly related to this question so i could mention here that E.Bakhoum 2002 (https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0206061) has suggested that the relativistic total energy of particle could be $E_{tot} = m\gamma v^2 = mc^2(\gamma - 1/\gamma)$ instead of $E_{tot} = m\gamma c^2$ such that the kinetic energy of the particle is the same $mc^2(\gamma -1)$ but the instead that there is rest energy $mc^2$, there would be component $mc^2(1-1/\gamma)$ that becomes zero when $ v \rightarrow 0$. In other words that there is no rest energy for particle in rest. This component also becomes $mc^2$ only if particle is moving close to velocity of light.

Comment: This question would be much more readable if it used Mathjax for equations and symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation makes a mistake by assuming the particle speed $v$ in the relativistic momentum equation is the same "$v$" that appears in the wave speed equation.

According to the de Broglie hypothesis for [matter waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) the energy and momentum of a particle are related to its frequency and wavelength following the same relations as for photons.

$$ E = hf = \hbar \omega \quad\quad p = \frac{h}{\lambda} = \hbar k, $$

where $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the wave and $k$ is the [wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber).

The [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) of any wave is given by
$$ v_\mathrm{phase} = \lambda f = \frac{\omega}{k}.$$

The speed of the particle is actually the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) of the wave, which differs from the phase velocity:
$$ v_\mathrm{particle} = v_\mathrm{group} = \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial k}.$$

We can show that the particle speed is the group velocity by directly calculating it, using the relativistic energy-momentum relation:
$$E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4.$$

The group velocity is:
$$v_\mathrm{group} = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left( \sqrt{p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4}\right) = \frac{pc^2}{\sqrt{p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4}} = \frac{pc^2}{E}.$$

Using the correct relativistic definitions for $E$ and $p$ this becomes:
$$v_\mathrm{group} = \frac{(\gamma m v)\,c^2}{\gamma mc^2} = v.$$

As an aside, proposing modifications to special relativity is an incredibly tricky business.  Special relativity is a core building block for many major results that followed.  For instance, quantum field theory makes very accurate prediction about things like the lifetimes of unstable particles and scattering cross sections in particle experiments.  You could redo all of these calculations assuming $E=\gamma mv^2$ were the correct form of relativistic energy.  This would lead to different predictions for these experiments.  I would guess these new predictions would be wrong, whereas using $E=\gamma mc^2$ for energy leads to predictions that agree with our experimental observations.

Answer (score 0):

Taking an approximate theory (nonrelativistic quantum mechanics) and torturing the symbols until something seemingly more interesting appears than the widely accepted more accurate theory (relativistic quantum mechanics) does not make much sense to me.

As you might already know, energy is only determined up to a constant in classical mechanics. In quantum field theory, the abitrariness of energy is even more pronounced in that there is [gauge invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory), which especially means that you can add a purely time dependent function (or the time derivative thereof) to the electric potential without changing the physics:
$$\Phi\to \Phi+\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}$$
In the following, I will assume $\hbar=e=1$ for the sake of simplicity.

Now, the above leads to the wave function attaining an additional arbitrary phase
$$\psi\to \psi\cdot e^{-i\varphi(t)}$$

In the special case where the additional phase is linearly rising
$$\varphi = \omega_0t$$
the electric potential (energy) is just shifted by an (arbitrary) constant
$$\Phi\to \Phi+\omega_0$$
The corresponding multiplication of the quantum mechanical wave function by a frequency factor
$$\psi\to \psi\cdot e^{-i\omega_0t}=\psi\cdot e^{-i2\pi f_0t}$$
is nothing but a complex amplitude modulation of the original wave function by the frequency $f_0$. If you apply that to a real-world mixture of frequencies, you are going to get sum and difference frequencies, or, in other words, beating. There is nothing mysterious about this at all.

But most importantly, you see by this example, that it does not make any sense to attribute anything physical to the frequency of a single particle with distinct momentum, simply because it is arbitrary (which is equivalent to not being observable). You always have to look at frequency **and** wavelength, to get the physics.